# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'. when updating to Support Library 26.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I've got this issue while updating to the latest Support Library version 26.0.0 (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0):

> Error:(18, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

```
/.../app/build/intermediates/res/merged/beta/debug/values-v26/values-v26.xml
Error:(15, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
Error:(18, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
Error:(15, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
Error:(18, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processBetaDebugResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

The file is from the support library:

```
<style name="Base.V26.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar" parent="Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:touchscreenBlocksFocus">true</item>
    <item name="android:keyboardNavigationCluster">true</item>
</style>
```

We're using the following versions:

```
ext.COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 26
ext.BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = "26.0.1"

ext.MIN_SDK_VERSION = 17
ext.TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 26
ext.ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = "26.0.0"
ext.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_LIBRARY_VERSION = "11.0.2"
```

---

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' + ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
compile 'com.android.support:design:' + ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:' + ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it remains an issue with the newest release (26.0.1): https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-1

Answer (score 315, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by updating sdk version and tools in gradle
 `compileSdkVersion 26`
 `buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"`

and `support library 26.0.1` https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-1

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to upgrade the google play services to 11.2 and then the above error came, and your answer didn't help. I also upgraded all the support stuff to 26.0.1 but still no luck. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: But updating to 26 will also have a major impact on many other things. Including notifications not working until proper Channels are created for Android 8.0 right ?

Comment: @patric Its compile SDK not target SDK.

Comment: If this solution dosen't work for you, check out Sam's answer below.

Comment: Working on Xamarin, I encountered this issue after installing android.support.v7.cardview. Downloading API 26 and updating all project settings to match this version did the trick. Looking forward to @Patric 's comment to see if it will have any side effect on my devs.

Comment: What if I don`t want to update the compileSdkVersion from 25 due to a business requirement? How to get rid of this?

Comment: I went ahead and updated the compileSdkVersion to 26

Answer (score 52):

Change
   Compile SDK Version:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
```

Build Tool Version:

```
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

Target SDK Version:

```
targetSdkVersion 26
```

Dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26+'
```

Sync Gradle.

Comment: getting warning : avoid using + in version number.

Comment: this worked for me. removed + from all to get rid of warnings

Comment: do not use +, you want to get reproducible builds and have full control on your dependencies. You don't want your app to start bugging after a new build because it quietly upgraded a lib...

Comment: You don't need to update the `targetSdkVersion` for this to work. Setting that to 26 will have other implications - i.e. you must make your app compatible for Android 8.0.

Comment: in which file i must add this things can you guide @ataulm

Comment: `build.gradle` in the `android` closure

Answer (score 35):

I had to change `compileSdkVersion = 26` and `buildToolsVersion = '26.0.1'` in all my dependencies `build.gradle` files

Comment: you should use a constant in gradle.properties for all your version numbers and use it in your build.gradle files:  api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$ANDROID_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION"

Answer (score 13):

In my react-native project, this error is generated in the `react-native-fbsdk`. Updating the `react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle` as following fixes the issue.

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

Comment: adding below to root build.gradle worked no need to edit the module's build.gradle file
`subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 26
                buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
            }
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 9):

I hit this exact same error and was Googling all over trying to find what I'm doing wrong as that is generated build values-26 code and not styles that I provided. I tried everything from Gradle 4.0 to Android Studio preview 3.0 to canary channel, you name it.

I never found the answer online. In the end, I was able to go back to standard Dev Android Studio and 2.3.3 Gradle as I ended up accidentally fixing it :).

Turned out I was so focused on updating my library project that I was not noticing that the error was caused from an unused sub module (demo app) that is nested in my library project. Once I updated the sub module to match the 26 build tools and 26+ design and support libraries my problem went away.

Not sure if that is what you are seeing as well, but personally I was only updating the lib to release again so wasn't caring about the sample app module, and the error sure appeared to be related to 26 sdk which I only touched in the lib module so wasn't thinking to check the other one. So that was the problem all along for me. Hopefully that fixes you as well. I had this error in 2 library projects and it fixed it in both.

Goodluck either way and if this doesn't resolve your issue, please share what did. BTW 26.0.01 build tools and 26.1.0 design and support is where I ended up going to in the end, although 26.0.1 worked fine as well.

Comment: It really solves the problem (if you have several modules)

Answer (score 8):

I had this exact error and I realized the my `compileSdkVersion` was set at `25` and my `buildToolsVersion` was set at `"26.0.1"`.

So I just changed the `compileSdkVersion` to `26` and synced the Gradle. it fixed the problem for me.

EDIT: my `targetSDKVersion` was also set as `26`

Answer (score 8):

I've had a similar error for react-native-youtube & react-native-orientation.

Figured out, that the build.gradle of those Project use `compileSdkVersion 23` but the Feature: android:keyboardNavigationCluster was added since `api 26` (android 8).

**So how to fix?**

One way to fix this easily is to edit your /android/build.gradle ( !!! NOT /android/app/build.gradle) and add those code at the bottom of the file.

This allow you to force the SDK and BuildTool-Version your submodules use:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I also faced this issue you just need to make 2 changes:

File Name : **android/build.gradle** mention this below code

```
subprojects {
   afterEvaluate { 
     project -> if (project.hasProperty("android")) { 
       android { 
        compileSdkVersion 26 buildToolsVersion '26.0.2' 
       } 
      }
    } 
}
```

File Name :**android/app/build.gradle**
change your compliesdk version and buildToolVersion like this:

```
compileSdkVersion 26 buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
```

and in

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with my Ionic 2 project, all I did to resolved the issues was

- Open "ionic_project_folder/platforms/android/project.properties"
- Change **target=android-25** to **target=android-26**
- Run `ionic build --release android`

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: My project change to `target=android-26` , but still showing this error

Answer (score 6):

```
//Adding this to the root build.gradle solved my problem, thanks @Yalamber
subprojects {
        afterEvaluate { project ->
            if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion 26
                    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you share more information with code for more understanding of your answer.

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: Thank you! Best answer. Essentially the project dependencies (node_modules projects) had differing sdk versions. Adding this code to the root level build.gradle ensures all these dependencies use the specified sdk version and the project is able to build. :D

Answer (score 4):

After updating your android studio to 3.0, if this error occurs just update the gradle properties, these are the settings which solved my issue:

```
compileSdkVersion 26

targetSdkVersion 26

buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
```

Comment: `26.0.2` build version fixed things for me.

Answer (score 3):

I updated my project `app/build.gradle` to have

```
compileSDkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
```

However, the problem was actually with the `react-native-fbsdk` package. I had to change the same settings in `node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle`.

Answer (score 3):

In android studio, 
right click on the project (since I had a Cordova project, I had CordovaLib and android: I selected android in my case),

1. Select Open Module Settings
2. In the Project Structure modal that pops up select the project in the modules section in the side panel (again android in my case)
3. Click on the Dependencies tab
4. Click on the green plus button in the top right corner
5. Select Library Dependency
6. Select app-compat-v7 from the dropdown
7. Clean project and rebuild

Comment: This is a much easier way of fixing this than manually editing all of the files.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue for one of my PhoneGap project (Android studio 3.0.1). To resolve this I have followed, the following step

1) Right click on Project name (In my Case android), select "Open Module Settings"

2) Select modules (android and CordovaLib)

3) Click properties on top

4) Chose Compile SDK version (I have chosen API 26: Android 8.0 )

5) Choose Build Tools Version (I have chosen 26.0.2)

6) Source Compatibility ( 1.6)

7) Target Compatibility ( 1.6)

Click Ok and rebuild project.

The following link shows my setting for step I have followed

https://app.box.com/s/o11xc8dy0c2c7elsaoppa0kwe1d94ogh https://app.box.com/s/ofdcg0a8n0zalumvpyju58he402ag1th

Answer (score 2):

I hit this recently and remember where it comes from.  It's a mismatch between the Xamarin.Android.* version and the installed Android SDK version.

The current VS2017 `15.5.3` new project defaults for nuGet `Xamarin.Android.*` are `25.4.0.2` and the default VS install for cross platform development are the following Android SDK packages:

- Android `7.1` - Nougat

  - Android SDK Platform `25`
  - Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image

If you upgraded you solution nuGet for `Xamarin.Android.*` to `26.1.0.1` then you will need to install the follow in the Android SDK:

- Android `8.0` - Oreo

  - Android SDK Platform `26`
  - Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image

Answer (score 2):

**when you try to change targetSDKVersion 26 to 25 that time occurred 
 i was found solution of No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'. when updating to Support Library 26.0.0**

**Just Chage This code from Your Build.gradle**

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**to**

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.2.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue when compile react-native-fbsdk

I resolved this issue by change `build.gradle` of `react-native-fbsdk`

from

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+')
```

to

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0')
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by one of the libraries for me that needed version 26 for compilation.

Making the targetSdkVersion to 26 will cause other issues and you will have to tweak your app to adapt to the Oreo platform. This is not the correct solution for all.

Just making the `compileSdkVersion to 26` and `buildToolsVersion to 26.0.2` worked for me.

One should also update all of their **support libraries to use 26.1.0 or later.**

Answer (score 1):

update these in gradle

compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by making some changes in build.gradle file

Changes in **root build.gradle** are as follows:

```
subprojects {
   afterEvaluate { 
     project -> if (project.hasProperty("android")) { 
       android { 
        compileSdkVersion 26 
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.1' 
       } 
      }
    } 
}
```

Changes in build.gradle are as follows:

```
compileSdkVersion 26 
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

and

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using nativescript and facing this issue: you can add

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
```

in App_Resources/Android/app.gradle (under `android {`)

Then run `tns platform remove android` and `tns build android` in your project root.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Android SDK 8.0 on your development environment. I was having the same issue on my MAC and installing SDK 8.0 and its tools fixed it. I am having the same issue on Windows. I am downloading the SDK now.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue with ionic .

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@6.4.0
```

And replace in platform/android/projet.properties

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4+
```

To

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:26+
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to do below things
1.right click the project click.

2.open module settings->in properties tab->change the compile sdk and build tool version into 26,26.0.0.

3.click ok.

Its working for me after an hour tried.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by doing the following:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
```

Comment: [Please only use English on this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676). If you prefer to use Portuguese, there is [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Just clear your project and build again.

```
./gradlew  app:clean app:assembleDebug
```

But it not works when targetSdkVersion or compileSdkVersion is 25.