# Firebase Auth Dependency causing gradle error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, build.gradle

I am learning Firebase and at a point, I had to add following code in app gradle

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.4.0'
```

and it shows following error

```
Error:(15, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 
'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
Error:(32, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 
'android:autofillHints'.
Error:(15, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 
'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The solution to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45310170/4815718) was to specify `compileSdkVersion 26` and `buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"` in the build.gradle file.  Are you using those versions?

Comment: You are correct. After using above settings, This issue was addressed.Thanks.