# No solution for: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio-3.0, gradle-dependencies

Getting this: **Error:(15, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'**.

Using Android Studio 3.0.1, react-native 0.48.2.

My current build.gradle(app):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.awesome"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile(project(':react-native-fbsdk')){
        exclude(group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk')
    }
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0"
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2"){
        force = true
    }
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'
    compile project(':react-native-spinkit')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.2') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile project(':react-native-google-places')
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.2"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2"
    compile project(':react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box')
    compile project(':react-native-svg')
    compile (project(':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation')){
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }
}
```

The gradlew app:dependencies

```
+--- project :react-native-google-signin
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 -> 26.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2 -> 27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2 -> 27.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.3
|    |    |    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.3
|    |    |    |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2 -> 27.0.2
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.2 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.2
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.2 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.2 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.51.0
|         +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|         +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 -> 26.0.2 (*)
|         +--- com.facebook.fbui.textlayoutbuilder:textlayoutbuilder:1.0.0
|         |    \--- com.facebook.fbui.textlayoutbuilder:staticlayout-proxy:1.0
|         +--- com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0
|         |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:drawee:1.3.0
|         |    |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:1.3.0
|         |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:1.3.0
|         |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:1.3.0
|         |         +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         |         +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:1.3.0
|         |         \--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:1.3.0
|         |              +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         |              \--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:1.3.0
|         +--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.3.0
|         |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0
|         |    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.11.0 -> 1.13.0
|         |    +--- com.facebook.fresco:fbcore:1.3.0
|         |    \--- com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:1.3.0 (*)
|         +--- com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.1.0
|         +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0
|         +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0 (*)
|         +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.6.0
|         |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0 (*)
|         +--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0
|         \--- org.webkit:android-jsc:r174650
+--- project :react-native-splash-screen
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 -> 26.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.51.0 (*)
+--- project :react-native-fbsdk
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0 -> 26.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.51.0 (*)
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.29.0
|    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|    |    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|    |    |         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1 -> 27.0.2
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.1 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.29.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.29.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1 -> 26.0.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1 -> 27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.1 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1 -> 27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.29.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.29.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.29.0 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.29.0
|    |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.29.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.29.0 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-places:4.29.0
|    |    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.29.0 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:4.29.0
|    |    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.29.0 (*)
|    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-messenger:4.29.0
|         \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.29.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2 (*)
+--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.51.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.6.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:11.6.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.2
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:11.6.2
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:11.6.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone-license:11.6.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:11.6.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:11.6.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.2 (*)
+--- project :react-native-spinkit
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.51.0 (*)
|    \--- com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0
+--- project :react-native-push-notification
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 -> 26.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.51.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+ -> 11.6.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:11.6.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid-license:11.6.2
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm-license:11.6.2
|    \--- me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.8
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.2 (*)
+--- project :react-native-google-places
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.51.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.4 -> 11.6.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.4 -> 11.6.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps-license:11.6.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-license:11.6.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4 -> 11.6.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location-license:11.6.2
|    \--- com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.2 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2 (*)
+--- project :react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.51.0 (*)
+--- project :react-native-svg
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1 -> 26.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.51.0 (*)
+--- project :react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation
|    +--- com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.51.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:+ -> 27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+ -> 11.6.2 (*)
|    +--- com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6
|    +--- com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6
|    |    +--- com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6
|    |    \--- com.github.tony19:apktool-lib:1.4.4-3
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21
\--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2
     \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.6.2
          +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 (*)
          +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.2
          |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 (*)
          |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.2 (*)
          |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common-license:11.6.2
          +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:11.6.2
          |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 (*)
          |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.6.2
          |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 (*)
          |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.2 (*)
          |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.2 (*)
          |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-license:11.6.2
          |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.6.2 (*)
          |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.6.2 (*)
          |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl-license:11.6.2
          \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-license:11.6.2
```

Tried many solutions as in:
[No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'. when updating to Support Library 26.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301203/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-androidkeyboardnavigationc)

Nothing worked!

Getting no red underlines in dependencies.

Any specific advice for this case? Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**
Some more information about the error:
(Fotgot to mention it, appears to be a problem in package react-native-fbsdk)

[The error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgyjD.png)

Comment: same problem for `buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"`?

Comment: Replace " compile com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0" with  "compile com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0"

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya tried buildToolsVersion "26.0.1", same problem

Comment: @Md.Didarulislam getting same error with 4.28.0

Answer (score 0):

Google Play services 11.6.2 depends on support libraries 27.0.2. But only on some of them.

Then you forced appcompat-v7 support library to version 26.0.2. This results in a conflict.

All imported support libraries need to have the same version, otherwise they will refer non-existent code and resources (such as style attributes) in other support libraries. Same thing goes for GMS + Firebase.

For now bump your appcompat-v7 version to 27.0.2 and keep it consistent in the future.

```
compile("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2") {
    force = true
}
```

Just as support library version 26 requires compile SDK version 26, support library version 27 requires your project compile against SDK version 27.

```
compileSdkVersion 27
```

That in turn *may* require build tools 27+.

```
buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
```

"May require" means that

- I didn't check
- Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0 automatically picks at least the minimum required (so you can delete the line altogether)

Comment: Tried, not working. Anyway, I'll keep the version 27.0.2. I made an edit: the error occured in the following location:
C:\tmp\SatisfAction\react-native-fbsdk\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v26\values-v26.xml

Comment: Follow link to solve  **v26‌​\values-v26.xm**  issue . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757074/react-native-fbsdk-error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-a/47786292#47786292 @BrunoConterato