# AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I'm using React Native and getting this error during build. I'm pretty sure it's because of the mismatch between the SDK and the support library but I couldn't find the correct values. What SDK version and support library should I use. Please help me I'm really in a tough spot.

```
:app:processDebugResources/Users/hg/Downloads/ecoway/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15:21-54: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

/Users/hg/Downloads/ecoway/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v26/values-v26.xml:18:21-54: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

/Users/hg/Downloads/ecoway/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

/Users/hg/Downloads/ecoway/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v26/values-v26.xml:18: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ecoway"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
            multiDexEnabled = true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
                        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':tipsi-stripe')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')

         compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1") {
                force = true;
            }
            compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1") {
                force = true;
            }
            compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1") {
                force = true;
            }
            compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1') {
                force = true;
            }
            compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1') {
                force = true;
            }


    compile project(':react-native-svg')
  compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    compile project(':react-native-audio-toolkit')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
                maven {
                    url "https://maven.google.com"
                }
    }
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'ecoway'
include ':tipsi-stripe'
project(':tipsi-stripe').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/tipsi-stripe/android')
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
include ':react-native-svg'
project(':react-native-svg').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-svg/android')
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
include ':react-native-image-crop-picker'
project(':react-native-image-crop-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/android')
include ':react-native-fs'
project(':react-native-fs').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fs/android')
include ':react-native-fcm'
project(':react-native-fcm').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fcm/android')
include ':react-native-audio-toolkit'
project(':react-native-audio-toolkit').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-audio-toolkit/android/lib')

include ':app'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'. when updating to Support Library 26.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301203/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-androidkeyboardnavigationc)

Comment: **REFERENCE** Check your Solution over this Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757074/react-native-fbsdk-error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-a/47786292#47786292

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I tried to upgrade from 25 to 26 Android version (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18095) but I could not do it because it react native does not support 26 yet and then I downgrade to 25 and I found the same issue,

This works for me...

build.gradle file

```
android {
 compileSdkVersion 25
 buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

defaultConfig {
 minSdkVersion 18
 targetSdkVersion 25

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk  android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
```

React-native version 0.47.2

Answer (score 0):

force Gradle to build all the dependencies with our main project SDK version and tools versions.
Add the following line to your project's `android/build.gradle` with your Android SDK dependency.

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

refer to this [link](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/882#issuecomment-405255785)