# Xamarin Forms, Android Build Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

after updating my libraries I had the error in Android project

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'. MyProject.Android C:\SSBMcopy\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.Android\obj\Debug__library_projects__\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\library_project_imports\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml 2

I installed Android SDK 26 but nothing changed.

How can I solve this?

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301203/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-androidkeyboardnavigationc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it by updating Visual Studio